# css3 media query not working in IE below ie10

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have created a responsive email template and the **problem is media queries are not working in below IE10 browser.** I have used js library to make it run but it is not working.

```
<head>
<title></title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


<style type="text/css">
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        /*widths for standard blocks*/
        table[class=w15], td[class=w15], img[class=w15] {width:15px !important;}
        table[class=w170], td[class=w170], img[class=w170] {width:290px !important;}
        table[class=w180], td[class=w180], img[class=w180] {width:145px !important;}
        table[class=w200], td[class=w200], img[class=w200] {width:320px !important;}
    }
</style>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
```

Web link url:

http://silista.in/praveen/template-1.html

Comment: Is there a special reason you're using `table[class=w15]` rather than `table.w15`?  The former won't work in anything older than IE9.

Comment: The reason for using `table[class=w15]` vs `table.w15` is how email providers handle classes and styles for mobile devices. That being said, @cimmanon is right. You are trying to test an email template in a web browser. You need to send tests through email programs or use email provider testing environments. Also, email programs will 100% ignore your JS.

Comment: I agree @disinfor you need table[class=w15] for Yahoo. But you shouldn't be testing in IE for responsive emails. best way to test is each of the clients. Once you get it perfect in the browser it will look different in outlook 2003 and 2007. Check out http://litmus.com/email-testing for testing and also agree that you CANNOT use JS in emails

Comment: @Travis yes i am using table[class=w15] for yahoo. I am going to check this in different email clients, if it works fine there than i will forget about IE browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Best media query hacks for IE would be

```
 IE10 @media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {}
 IE8 @media \0screen {}
 IE7 @media screen\9 {}
```

You can add your IE specific CSS code within any of the media queries above.

Read more here: http://browserhacks.com/

Answer (score 0):

I also saw IE 9 is  @media screen and (min-width:0\0) {}

Question - Can you just add that snippet of code in the style tags or do you also need to add all applicable CSS in between the { }?