# Media Queries not working in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: css, media-queries

These media queries are working well in other browsers except IE10, In this situation what should I do? How can I achieve this task?

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 575.98px){
  .layer-hover .plus, .layer-hover-2 .plus{
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
  .layer-hover a, .layer-hover-2 a{
    width: 70%;
    padding: 5px 0;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css3 media query not working in IE below ie10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957167/css3-media-query-not-working-in-ie-below-ie10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few resources here on @media usage on Internet Explorer 11 and under.

- [Targetting Internet Explorer Best Practices](https://philipnewcomer.net/2014/04/target-internet-explorer-10-11-css/)
- [CanIUse @Media (Shows known issues with IE10)](https://caniuse.com/#search=%40media)
- [Browser Compatability Best Practices.](https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)
- [IE10 Specific Styles (Some techniques)](https://css-tricks.com/ie-10-specific-styles/)
- [IE10 CSS Hacks](https://www.impressivewebs.com/ie10-css-hacks/)
- [IE10 vs Media Queries](http://arleym.com/ie10-vs-media-queries/)

Some people have been known to try tricks like below as well with success, but IE10 can be unforgiving. Note the prefixes and see the CanIUse Knowledge Objects.

```
@-ms-viewport {
width: device-width;
}
```

If that doesn't do the trick, you could try removing the `screen` parameter 
 and styling specifically for IE10 like so.

[Per this article on targeting IE10](https://css-tricks.com/ie-10-specific-styles/), this little workaround exists since conditional comments aren't recognized since IE10.

```
@media (max-width: 575.98px)[data-useragent*='MSIE 10.0']{
     .layer-hover .plus {
         font-size: 2.5rem;
    }
     layer-hover-2 .plus[data-useragent*='MSIE 10.0'] {
         font-size: 2.5rem;
    }
     .layer-hover a[data-useragent*='MSIE 10.0']{
         width: 70%;
         padding: 5px 0;
         font-size: 10px;
    }
     .layer-hover-2 a[data-useragent*='MSIE 10.0'] {
         width: 70%;
         padding: 5px 0;
         font-size: 10px;
    }
}
```

Another possible hack you could try is mentioned on [Mediacurrent with lots of success stories.](https://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/pro-tip-how-write-conditional-css-ie10-and-11/)

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
    // IE10+ CSS here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your valueable resources, first div _**.layer-hover .plus**_  is works, Unfortunately, another div _**.layer-hover-2 .plus**_  not working ....

Comment: Could you update your question with comparison of code that works and code that doesn't so we can isolate the cause?

Comment: Oh actually, lets just remove the comma and create individual rules to see if that works. See my updated answer in a moment.

Comment: I did it bro, Unfortunately Output is same !

Comment: Added another option you can try. Considering reading each of those articles and trying all the techniques outlined.